# Module dependencies

Tags: gcc, apache-httpd

In a system, I need to use `module load gcc/4.4.7` to get access to `gcc` to compile `foobar.c` into `foobar`.

When I run `foobar`, does `gcc/4.4.7` need to be loaded, say to ensure certain libraries are available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I need to use module load gcc/4.4.7 to get access to gcc to compile foobar.c into foobar then when I run foobar, does gcc/4.4.7 need to be loaded first?

No.  Gcc is a compiler that creates executables from source code.  Once an executable is made, the compiler is not involved with running it.